# How do you turn a crossfilter (i.e. multi-dimensional array) back into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, crossfilter

For example, lets say I transformed this array into a crossfilter by doing the following

```
var Array = [
            {Id: "01", Name: "A", Price: "1.00", Quantity: "1"},
            {Id: "02", Name: "B", Price: "10.00", Quantity: "1"},
            {Id: "04", Name: "C", Price: "9.50", Quantity: "10"},
            {Id: "03", Name: "a", Price: "9.00", Quantity: "2"},
            {Id: "06", Name: "b", Price: "100.00", Quantity: "2"},
            {Id: "05",Name: "c", Price: "1.20", Quantity: "2"}
        ];

var ndx = crossfilter(Array);
```

How do I change it from the multi-dimensional array back into it's original form above, which was originally defined in Array

I've tried the following function

```
function transform_back_to_array(ndx){
var f = eval(ndx)
return JSON.stringify(f)
};
```

The output should be the following, which should be the same as the original:

```
[
                {Id: "01", Name: "A", Price: "1.00", Quantity: "1"},
                {Id: "02", Name: "B", Price: "10.00", Quantity: "1"},
                {Id: "04", Name: "C", Price: "9.50", Quantity: "10"},
                {Id: "03", Name: "a", Price: "9.00", Quantity: "2"},
                {Id: "06", Name: "b", Price: "100.00", Quantity: "2"},
                {Id: "05",Name: "c", Price: "1.20", Quantity: "2"}
            ];
```

See this codepen for my attempt of turning the original array back into its original form, as well: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/MYPEwY

In a [crossfilter tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/693841/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-Using-Crossfil), the following function was used to print the results of ndx the console. I believe this has some clues:

```
function print_filter(filter){
    var f=eval(filter);
    if (typeof(f.length) != "undefined") {}else{}
    if (typeof(f.top) != "undefined") {f=f.top(Infinity);}else{}
    if (typeof(f.dimension) != "undefined") {f=f.dimension(function(d) { return "";}).top(Infinity);}else{}
    console.log(filter+"("+f.length+") = "+JSON.stringify(f).replace("[","[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g,"},\n\t").replace("]","\n]"));
};
```

Comment: Can you write an output array you want

Comment: I can't get over the fact that you can print crossfilter to the console, but you can't simply change it back to an array. For example, see the print_filter function above.

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is exactly you're trying to do here? You've printed the same array object twice saying this is the way it is and this is the way you want it. From what I can see, they're exactly the same. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In short, I want to be able to take an array, transform it to a crossfilter, and transform it back to an array. The reason that I want to transform it back to an array is because I'd like to use the data that was filtered with crossfilter into a function that can only take in arrays and not crossfilters. Does that make sense?

Comment: `print_filter()` retrieves records using [`.top(Infinity)`](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_top), with `.dimension(function () {...})` since `.top()` isn't a method of the `crossfilter` itself.